# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=1$$
Beta function

$${1\over {2n\choose n}}=n\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^ndx$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n\over {2n\choose n}}=\int_{0}^{1}{2(1-t)\over [1-2t(1-t)]^2}dt$$

We can split out the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{n-1}(n^2-n\pi+1)\over (2n+1){2n\choose n}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{n-1}(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+3){2n\choose n}}=1$$

With out the denominator $2n+1$ and $2n+3$ We can apply the beta function directly and integrate. I don't how to get the factors $2n+1$ and $2n+3$ with the beta function. Any hints on how to prove S?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765705/how-can-we-show-that-sum-n-0-infty-frac2nnn-pi31-pi2n2n-1/1766499#1766499

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer  is divided  into  several steps.

> **Overview:**
>
> At first  we show
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)\qquad\qquad  |x|<1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> With   a    *small  trick* we derive the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
> =\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)
> \end{align*}
>   just as intermediate step to derive the following series as basis for further calculations:
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x):=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{n}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
> =\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}-1}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> Since  we have to additionally respect the factor $(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)$ in the numerator of OPs series we apply the differential operator $D_x$ and calculate from $A(x)$
>   \begin{align*}
> (xD_x)^kA(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^k(2x)^{n}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\qquad\qquad k=1,\ldots,4
> \end{align*}
>   These are  the *building blocks* to finally calculate OPs series.

$$ $$

> **Generating function with reciprocal central binomial coefficient:**
>
> The central binomial coefficient can be represented with the *[Betafunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)* as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}&=\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{n\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\\
> &=n\beta(n+1,n)\\
> &=n\int_0^1t^n(1-t)^{n-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x)^{2n}\int_0^1t^n(1-t)^{n-1}dt\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-t}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty(4x^2t)^n(1-t)^{n}dt\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-t}\int_0^1\frac{4x^2t}{1-4x^2t(1-t)}dt
> \end{align*}

Substituting $x(2t-1)=s$ gives
\begin{align*}
x(2t-1)&=s\qquad &x^2(4t^2-4t+1)&=s^2\\
2xdt&=ds\qquad &4x^2t^2-4x^2t&=s^2-x^2
\end{align*}

> We get
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}&=\int_{-x}^x\frac{s+x}{s^2+(1-x^2)}ds\\
> &=\left.\frac{1}{2}\log(s^2-x^2+1)\right|_{-x}^{x}+\left.\frac{x}{1-x^2}\arctan\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\right|_{-x}^x\\
> &=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\\
> &=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin\left(\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}+1}}\right)\\
> &=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin\left(x\right)\\
> \end{align*}
>   and (1) follows.

$$ $$

> **Generating function of $A(x)$:**
>
> We derive a generating function for
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{n}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We do it in three steps. At first we show
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Since 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{2(n+1)^2}{2(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{n+1}\cdot\frac{((n+1)!)^2}{(2n+2)!}\\
&=\frac{2}{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}^{-1}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> we get from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
> &=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(n+1)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}\\
> &=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n-2}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)\\
> &=1+\frac{2}{3}x^2+\frac{8}{15}x^4+\frac{16}{35}x^6+\frac{128}{315}x^8+\cdots
> \end{align*}

Substituting $n$ with $n+1$ in (4) gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2n+3}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}^{-1}=\frac{2}{n+2}\binom{2n+4}{n+2}^{-1}
\end{align*}

> We get from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n+3)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}
> &=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(n+2)\binom{2n+4}{n+2}}\tag{5}\\
> &=2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n-4}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)-\frac{1}{4x^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{15}x^2+\frac{4}{35}x^4+\frac{32}{315}x^6+\frac{64}{693}x^8+\cdots
> \end{align*}

On the other hand we get from (4)
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2n+3}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}^{-1}=\frac{1}{2n+3}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}
\end{align*}

> and from this identity we obtain from (5)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n+3)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(2x)^{2n}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin(x)-\frac{1}{4x^2}
> \end{align*}

We want to get rid of $n+1$ in the numerator in (6) in order    to obtain the series $A(x)$. We  substitute
\begin{align*}
x\rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}
\end{align*}
and then we integrate the series.

We obtain from (6) by this substitution
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n
&=\frac{1}{4\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{2}}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2u}\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u(2-u)}}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2u}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{15}u+\frac{1}{35}u^2+\frac{4}{315}u^3+\frac{4}{693}u^4+\frac{8}{3003}u^5+\cdots
\end{align*}

> Integrating the RHS of (7) with the help of Wolfram Alpha gives $A(u)$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(u)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u}\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)\tag{8}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{30}u+\frac{1}{105}u^2+\frac{1}{315}u^3+\frac{4}{3465}u^4+\frac{4}{9009}u^5+\cdots\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (2) follows.

$$ $$

> **Building blocks: $(uD_u)^kA(u)$**
>
> The next step is to successively apply the operator $uD_u$ on $A(u)$ with $D_u$ the differential operator. We obtain with some help of Wolfram Alpha
>   \begin{align*}\
> (uD_u)A(u)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n2^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n\\
> &=-\frac{3}{2u}+\frac{3-u}{u^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)\tag{9}\\
> &=\frac{1}{30}u+\frac{2}{105}u^2+\frac{1}{105}u^3+\frac{16}{3465}u^4+\frac{20}{9009}u^5+\cdots\\
> \\
> (uD_u)^2A(u)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^22^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n\\
> &=\frac{4u-9}{2u(u-2)}+\frac{u^2-7u+9}{u^2(u-2)\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)\tag{10}\\
> &=\frac{1}{30}u+\frac{4}{105}u^2+\frac{1}{35}u^3+\frac{64}{3465}u^4+\frac{100}{9009}u^5+\cdots\\
> \\
> (uD_u)^3A(u)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^32^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n\\
> &=-\frac{5u^2-25u+27}{2u(u-2)^2}-\frac{u^3-13u^2+34u-27}{u^2(u-2)^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)\tag{11}\\
> &=\frac{1}{30}u+\frac{8}{105}u^2+\frac{3}{35}u^3+\frac{256}{3465}u^4+\frac{500}{9009}u^5+\cdots\\
> \\
> (uD_u)^4A(u)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^42^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}u^n\\
> &=\frac{6u^3-53u^2+115u-81}{2u(u-2)^3}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{u^4-23u^3+89u^2-142u+81}{u^2(u-2)^3\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}}\cdot\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}\right)\tag{12}\\
> &=\frac{1}{30}u+\frac{16}{105}u^2+\frac{9}{35}u^3+\frac{1024}{3465}u^4+\frac{2500}{9009}u^5+\cdots\\
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Building blocks at $u=1$**
>
> We have now all the building blocks we need and derive from (8) to (12) some nice identities by setting $u=1$ and noting that $\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(1)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=1-\frac{1}{4}\pi\\
> \left.(uD_u)A(u)\right|_{u=1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n2^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\pi\\
> \left.(uD_u)^2A(u)\right|_{u=1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^22^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\pi\\
> \left.(uD_u)^3A(u)\right|_{u=1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^32^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=-\frac{7}{2}+\frac{5}{4}\pi\\
> \left.(uD_u)^4A(u)\right|_{u=1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^42^{n-1}}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{13}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\pi
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **OPs series:**
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> (n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)=n^4+(1-\pi)n^3-\pi n^2+(1+\pi)n-1
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain by putting all together in OPs series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}&{2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^4+(1-\pi)n^3-\pi n^2+(1+\pi)n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}\\
> &=2\left.(uD_u)^4A(u)\right|_{u=1}+2(1-\pi)\left.(uD_u)^3A(u)\right|_{u=1}\\
> &\qquad-2\pi\left.(uD_u)^2A(u)\right|_{u=1}+2(1+\pi)\left.(uD_u)A(u)\right|_{u=1}-2A(1)\\
> &=2\left(\frac{13}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)+2(1-\pi)\left(-\frac{7}{2}+\frac{5}{4}\pi\right)
> -2\pi\left(\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\pi\right)\\
> &\qquad+2(1+\pi)\left(-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)-2\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

**Note:** The proof of (1) is Theorem 1 in B. Sury's paper *[Identities Involving Reciprocals of Binomials](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Sury/sury99.pdf)*. The *small trick* can be found e.g. in the proof of Theorem 2.1 in *[Sums of reciprocals of the central binomial coefficients](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf)* by R. Sprugnoli.

Comment: Q.E.D. @Markus Scheuer. This is what the OP really looking for step by step.

Comment: @Chinacat: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: it is more than useful, it is a very good knowledge you have shown to me. If I understand this properly, hopefully I can solve my other similar series problems. Thank you again.

Comment: @Chinacat: This was high speed! :-) Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.

Comment: @Chinacat: Some references added at the end of my answer which might be helpful. Regards,

Answer (score 6):

Through Euler's beta function you may prove that:
$$ \forall x\in(0,4), \qquad f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{x(4-x)}} \tag{1}$$
(have also a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878477/a-closed-form-of-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k1k-gamma2-left-frack2)), then by computing $\int x^2 f(x^2)\,dx$ we get:
$$ \forall x\in(0,2),\quad g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n+3)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4 \left(x \sqrt{4-x^2}-(4-x^2)\arcsin\frac{x}{2}\right)}{x^3 \sqrt{4-x^2}}\tag{2}$$
that is more than enough to prove your claim.

Comment: This is not going into my head!

Answer (score 6):

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$

Using Beta function, we can express 
$${2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}} = {(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over {n+1}}\int_{t=0}^1 T^{n+1} dt,$$ where $T =2t(1-t)$. To verify, see that $$\int_{t=0}^1 T^{n+1} dt = 2^{n+1}\beta(n+2,n+2) = 2^{n+1} \frac{(n!)^2 (n+1)^2}{(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!} = 2^{n} \frac{ (n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}.$$

We further have $$(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1) = n^4 +n^3 -n^3\pi-n^2\pi +n(\pi+1)-1.$$ Thus,

$${2^n(n^2-n\pi+1)(n^2+n-1)\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}} = \int_{t=0}^1T^{n+1}\left(n^3 -\pi n^2+(\pi+1)-\frac{\pi+2}{n+1}\right)dt. $$

Thus, 
$$S= \int_{t=0}^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1}\left(n^3 -\pi n^2+(\pi+1)-\frac{\pi+2}{n+1}\right)dt$$

$$S= \int_{t=0}^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1}n^3 -\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1}n^2+(\pi+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1}\frac{\pi+2}{n+1}\right)dt$$

$$S= \int_{t=0}^1 \left(\frac{T^2(1+4T+T^2)}{(1-T)^4} -\pi \displaystyle \frac{T^2(1+T)}{(1-T)^3}+(\pi+1)\frac{T}{1-T}+\ln(1-T)({\pi+2})\right)dt.$$

Substitute back $T=2t(1-t)$ and integrate to get the result. Hope this helps. Using http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%282t%281-t%29%29%5E2%2A%281%2B4%2A%282t%281-t%29%29%2B%282t%281-t%29%29%5E2%29%2F%281-%282t%281-t%29%29%29%5E4%20-pi%2A%282t%281-t%29%29%5E2%2A%281%2B%282t%281-t%29%29%29%2F%281-%282t%281-t%29%29%29%5E3%20%2B%20%28pi%2B1%29%2A%282t%281-t%29%29%2F%281-%282t%281-t%29%29%29%2B%28pi%2B2%29%2Alog%281-%282t%281-t%29%29%29&intvar=t&lbound=0&ubound=1&simplify=1, we have the result as 1 where that link will provide all the detailed steps for this integration. Thus, the required solution $S=1$ has been proved.